# floatrow: change caption position in odd and even pages

Tags: floatrow

I want to use captions beside figures, so I used the `floatrow` package. Yet, as illustrated below, I can't auto change the positioning of the caption text from left to right, depending on odd or even page.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[paperheight=24.0cm, paperwidth=20cm, top=1.75cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=2.0cm,right=6.0cm, headsep=0.25cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[widefigure]{margins=hangleft,capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top,left},floatwidth=\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[6]

\begin{figure*}[htp]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image_test.png}
\caption{This is the first caption text}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[6] \lipsum[6] \lipsum[6] \lipsum[6]

\begin{figure*}[htp]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image_test.png}
\caption{This is the second caption text}
\end{figure*}


\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does the 2nd figure have a number and not the 1st??

Comment: That is because the first figure has been left hand cropped .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use something like this.  I create the `altfig` environment that calls on the macro `\csname floatsetup\mypage\endcsname` before invoking `figure*`.  The value of `\mypage` is toggled at every shipout, so that one of two `\floatsetup`s are used, alternating page by page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage {atbegshi}
\usepackage[paperheight=24.0cm, paperwidth=20cm, top=1.75cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=2.0cm,right=6.0cm, headsep=0.25cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{floatrow}


\def\mypage{0}
\AtBeginShipout{\ifnum\mypage=0\relax\gdef\mypage{1}%
  \else\gdef\mypage{0}\fi}
\expandafter\def\csname floatsetup0\endcsname{%
  \floatsetup[widefigure]
    {margins=hangright,capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top,right},
    floatwidth=\textwidth}}
\expandafter\def\csname floatsetup1\endcsname{%
  \floatsetup[widefigure]
    {margins=hangleft,capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top,left},
    floatwidth=\textwidth}}

\newenvironment{altfig}[1][htbp]{\csname floatsetup\mypage\endcsname%
\begin{figure*}[#1]}{\end{figure*}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[6]

\begin{altfig}[htp]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image_test.png}
\caption{This is the first caption text}
\end{altfig}

\lipsum[6] \lipsum[6] \lipsum[6] \lipsum[6]

\begin{altfig}[htp]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image_test.png}
\caption{This is the second caption text}
\end{altfig}

\lipsum[6-8]

\begin{altfig}[htp]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image_test.png}
\caption{This is the third caption text}
\end{altfig}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, seems to work, yet I can't get rid off the demo picture (black square) and use a real picture instead. What should I change in the code?

Comment: I just had to remove the `[demo]` from the `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`. It works fine.

Comment: @user3060854 Indeed.  Demo mode is for those who don't have access to your images.  Alternately, it is common for people to develop MWE's using images from the `mwe` package, such as `example-image`, etc.

Comment: Just a last question. Is this possible to work with tables as well? (posistioning the caption of the tables left or right). If so, should I create a new environment? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user3060854 Yes it can, and yes, a new environment would be called for, so that you can invoke the current `\floatsetup` just prior to entering the `table`.

Comment: I couldn't repeat it with tables, so I created a new question in order to be fully answered https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371234/floatrow-change-caption-position-in-odd-and-even-pages-continued . I would appreciated if you could also help there.